# OpenLayers freehand polygon without elastic line to starting point

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Using the (wonderful) JavaScript OpenLayers library is there a way to allow freehand drawing of a polygon that does not have the final point always connected to the first point but rather only upon mouse up the polygon is completed and gets filled in?

An example to get a sense of what I mean: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html

Select polygon, then hold shift to do a freehand drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class that can handle it : http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Path-js.html

Comment: I will look into it. Any examples would be helpful.